# Not seeing my view at api/docs. Not sure if its the url or the request im trying itself

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

The idea is to make POST, GET and DELETE requests for photos. When I try regestering the url at URL pattern nothing is showing yet im also not getting any errors. I feel like this should be a fairly easy fix no?

views.py

```
class GroundsDrivewayPhotosViewSet(APIView):
    """Manage comments in the database."""
    serializer_class = serializers.GroundsDrivewayPhotosSerializer
    queryset = GroundsDrivewayPhotos.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    @api_view(['POST', 'GET', 'DELETE'])
    def upload_grounds_driveway_photo(self, request, pk=None):
        """Upload an image to report."""
        report = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(report, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Filter queryset to authenticated user."""
        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by(
            'grounds_driveway_photos')
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'report'

urlpatterns = [
    path('photos/grounds-driveway-photos',
    views.GroundsDrivewayPhotosViewSet.as_view(), name="grounds-driveway-photos")
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by nothing is showing? Just a blank page? Can you comment the authentication and permission, then recheck.

Comment: Theres a lot more than photos with this project but basically everything but the photos api views are showing in the schema. I also commented out the auth and they still arent showing up.